# Make UI uneditable when we are moving from one page to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to do userLogin through a webservice. The project is using Bootstrap for css and angular in the backend.
I am having a login Screen with a hidden div that is shoown when user click login button.Its a animated login icon.
Everything is working fine.I just want to make the background that is whole page including the userId, password  uneditable as well as signin button unclickable.

Comment: give us some code to work with :)

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the login button you can make the input(s) and button(s) disabled to make sure they remain unchanged.

When you get a result from your REST call you can re-enable them all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have a variable `$scope.loginIn` on your controller scope since you are showing an animated login icon while login. If you don't, add it to your login function, something like :

```
$scope.login = function(...) {
    $scope.loginIn = true;
    loginService.login(...).finally() {
        $scope.loginIn = false;
    }
}
```

then just use it on your input and buttons to disable them :

```
<div class="login">
    <input enable="!loginIn">...</input>
    <button enable="!loginIn">...</button>
</div>
```

(That might be off the context, if you give me some code I could probably be more accurate in my answer)